# CodeIngniter: как переслать данные во view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Помогите получить данные в View.

controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class First extends CI_Controller {
public function new_models(){  
      $this->load->model('new_models');
      $dast=$this->new_models->gets();
      print_r($dast);//выводит +!
      $this->load->view('new_view',$dast);
      }
}
```

model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class New_models extends CI_Model {

    function gets(){
        $query=$this->db->get('ti');
        return $query->result_array();
        }
}
```

view

```
<h3>this is new _view!!!</h3>
<?php print_r($dast); ?>
```

Получаю данные из модели в контроллер.`print_r($dast);` Все работает. Теперь не могу отправить данные в view. Ошибка:

> `A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Undefined variable: dast
> Filename: views/new_view.php
> Line Number: 11`

Comment: Русская документация здесь http://cidocs.ru/210/index.html версия 2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->load->view('new_view',array( 'dast' => $dast ) );
```

Comment: Спасибо,получилось.А где почитать подробнее про пересылку не подскажешь?

Comment: про пересылку чего?

Comment: про то, как параметры пересылки задавать ...хотя я кое-что нашел

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: Photon еще http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/helpers.html (может кому будет полезно еще)